# Android- how do mix audio and audio with ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want mux video and audio out 1 video use run cmd ffmpeg.and length = length audio or video min. Not replacing the sound of the sound of audio videos.
I want to mix two sounds together
Can u help me, please.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: i want mix audio in audioFile and audio in ideoFile

Answer (score 1):

Use the [amerge filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge):

```
ffmpeg -i video_and_audio_input -i audio_input \
-filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -ac 2 \
-map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output
```

All inputs must have the same sample rate and format. If they are not, then use the [aformat filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat) first.

If inputs do not have the same duration then output will stop with the shortest.

Comment: The video stream should be copied.

Comment: @Mulvya Since so little info was provided I assumed that the various streams are possibly not compatible, and it is unknown what the input formats are and what the desired output format is, hence no stream copy. I'll add it anyway.